# Разработка алгоритма заполнения таблицы (эвристический)

Tags: c#, алгоритм, .net, комбинаторика

Подскажите в какую сторону думать.
Необходимо придумать алгоритм заполнения таблицы.
Нужно заполнить нужные ячейки, так чтобы в каждой строке(B) было было заполнено k ячеек, в каждом столбце(N) было заполнено r ячеек и чтобы каждая случайная пара ячеек повторялась встречалась в двух(s) строках.
Все что есть, это, то что всегда соблюдены условия:

- Bk=Nr
- r(k-1)=L(N-1)
- B>=N
- r>=k

Пробовал просто в ручную, с разными сдвигами, но уже после 3-4 строк путаница.
Вот пример результата.
[image: Пример результата]
<sub>(источник: [joxi.ru](http://joxi.ru/l2ZXYQns6OlgrJ.png))</sub>

Comment: Эээ... А что означает «чтобы каждая случайная пара ячеек повторялась встречалась в двух(L) строках»? Что есть «каждая случайная пара ячеек»?

Comment: @VladD то есть каждая пара различных ячеек должна быть в двух строках. Например в первой строке заполнена 1 и 3 ячейка и во второй строке так же. То есть каждая пара повторяется ровно 2 раза.

Comment: @VladD вот пример того что должно получиться. [Пример](http://joxi.ru/l2ZXYQns6OlgrJ)

Comment: Картинка не грузится. Каждая пара ячеек лежит ровно в одном месте. Или вы имеете в виду _значения_, записанные в ячейках?

Comment: @VladD Изначально во всех значениях 0, заполнить - значит поставить 1. Про каждую пару значит что если в первой строке в первом и третьем столбце стоит 1, то и в любой другой строке там должны быть единицы. То есть пара, как вы правильно поправили, значений повторится. Аналогия: турнирная таблица, в каждом раунде фиксированное число команд, каждая команда играет фиксированное число раундов, каждая пара команд встречается ровно в 2 раундах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Шахматная аналогия

Спортивная аналогия в данном случае более чем уместна.
Случай на картинке полностью аналогичен игре в шахматы 
по швейцарской системе **B = 15** участниками в **k / 2 = 2** тура двумя цветами
за **N = 10** игровых дней (по одному туру в день) на **r / 2 = 3** досках.
Дополнительное условие: каждый участник играет не более одного тура в день.
Соответственно к этому вопросу и будем подходить.

### 2. Пары сетей

Для каждой сети s создаём массив из **B - 1** остальных сетей и заводим убывающий счётчик пар **c = k / 2**.
Когда сформирована пара сетей, то из их массивов следует удалить другую сеть,
а счётчики пар уменьшить на единицу. При обнулении счётчика - сбросить соответствующий массив.

Все возможные наборы пар для первой сети - это сочетания из **B - 1** элементов его массива по **k / 2**.
Для последующих сетей вопрос определяется их массивами и счётчиками пар.

### 3. Привязка пар сетей к узлам

Для каждой пары последовательных узлов создаём массив из **B** сетей и убывающий счётчик **c1 = r / 2**.  После привязки пары сетей к паре узлов вычёркиваем каждый узел из массива и уменьшаем счётчик. При обнулении счётчика сбрасываем соответствующий массив.

Параллелльно с привязкой ведём заполнение таблицы. По окончании привязки таблица будет заполнена требуемым образом.